# How does Google know I have HOLA vpn installed when it's not running?

Tags: vpn, captcha

I installed Hola and my google search was redirected to a Google page stating " "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network" and made me enter a CAPTCHA to prove I'm not a bot.

Here's some info about it:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en

*Google Search blocks IPs, IP ranges, and in some cases, whole ISPs, when a large percent of the traffic entering our networks is abusive.
If the blocking started within the past few weeks, it is likely to be related to the use of the "Hola VPN" browser plugin, or a program for Mac/Win/Android/iOS. The best thing to do is to uninstall the Hola VPN from your computer or network.*

My question is, if the program is closed and not in my startup items, what would trigger Google to know about the program just off a search?  I was still getting that redirect message on Google searches until I uninstalled the program.

Just for clarity, I wasn't searching with the Hola Chromium, I was using Firefox with no Hola are other similar add-ons installed.

Answer (score 2):

Hola channels other users traffic through your machine.  I would imagine (haven't checked / tested) that it installs as a service and runs in the background all the time, so Google noticed the traffic coming through your machine.

Just because the 'program is closed and not in my startup items', this does not mean that it is not running.

EDIT: you may also wish to review the information on http://adios-hola.org/ , which suggests there are a number of serious issues with 'hola'.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP might got banned, so you should change it. Restart your router/modem or just reconnect your internet. This is probably because the browser detected the VPN. Also check in your adapter settings if there is anything bridged to a VPN virtual device.

Comment: On most internet connections restarting the modem/router is not guaranteed to change the IP address (unless the DHCP address provided to the modem/router has expired (which can take a number of days), and even then you may well get the same IP address). You will almost certainly get a new one if you change your modem/router MAC address.

Comment: Normally after disconnecting and connecting again it should be changed. I have this experience. But dont know if it is exactly the same on yours.

Comment: If it was that easy pages like http://www.whereisip.net/changeip.html would not exist. I have had several different cable modem connections over the last 20 years or so, all with dynamic public IP addresses. The IP addresses never changed (except when there was a prolonged IPS outage) if my modem was powered off and restarted some hours later.

Comment: I used the re-connect method to change my ip to use multiple minecraft accounts on the same server because I would get kicked or banned if they notice multi-accounting :D

Comment: That's why I said "restarting the modem/router is not **guaranteed** to change the IP address". For some people it will work. For others it will not.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I gave an upvote to the above answer  of @BlueCompute. It's more correct and should be marked as the correct answer.